# Writing web based/desktop application

Tags: web-applications, desktop-application

I want to create a simple program similar to http://www.basecamphq.com/ that allows you to track progression and completion on projects that will work across a computer network or by the web (really which ever is the easiest to accomplish)

The program would be relatively simple but need to have a database that could be edited using a simple interface that would then update for all users.I'd like to make this with freeware. Regarding languages what would be a suitable one to use. Could this be achieved using php and MySQl or is there a better alternative?

Many thanks for any answers

Answer (score 4):

It can be done easily with PHP/MySQL **it's all about which language and systems you are more familiar with** that.

Other than almost all popular web languages will do. But you can't go wrong with PHP and ASP.NET or Ruby On Rails.

Answer (score 0):

PHP and MySQL would be more than enough for your needs. If you need a simple interface to edit your database, you can look into [PHPMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) as your database interface if you didn't want to use the built-in MySQL tools.

Answer (score 0):

Basecamp itself is written in Ruby on Rails, by the same people who gave Ruby on Rails to the world. So that's obviously a good place to start. Is there anything in particular you think is missing from Basecamp, or why do you want to reinvent that particular wheel? (Mind you it has been invented over and over again.)

Answer (score 0):

basecamp was developed in ruby on rails - in fact rails is essentially a framework that was lifted out of that and other applications. So rails is a good choice, since it's already tuned for exactly that kind of application.

I also suspect you'll probably be amazed at just how easy and quick it is to get about 80% of the functionality of basecamp in your own rails app. Be prepared for at least a week or two of learning curve, but it's worth it.